# py2pp "No module named ..."

Tags: py2app

I am trying to compile an app that works fine in alias mode (I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVOoHL2Bp_o). However, when running the "python3 setup.py py2app" I get the error: "ImportError: No module named PyInstaller.hooks.hook-PyQt5.QtWinExtras".

I tried to install the unfound module. This seems to solve the immediate issue but upon attempting to compile again, there is another "No module named" error for another module. This keeps going forever.

Can anybody help? I just started programming, my tech skills are quite low. Would be great to get help with easy words :) Thank you so much!

I tried to install the unfound module. This seems to solve the immediate issue but upon attempting to compile again, there is another "No module named" error for another module. This keeps going forever.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myFile.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Add your relevant code and output to the question as text, no videos!